# C# Reflection -Missing Fields?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm using reflection to create a new instance `Item B` from an instance of `Item A`. These are different objects, but share some level of commonality. In this sample case, they both inherit from a base class.

Base Class:

```cs
public abstract class Common
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public virtual string Ignored { get; }
}
```

I then have two classes that I am working with, the original class, and the output:

```cs
public class Original : Common
{
    public override string Ignored => "This will get ignored";
}

public class Output : Common { }
```

If I create a new instance of `Original` and give the `Value Property` a value, the I am able to see that value within one of the auto-generated backing fields. All of this using reflection, I can then use the `Activator` to create an instance of my `Output` class and am able to set the value of the `Value Property`

My process is to find the commonality, get all fields (properties if based on an interface) of that object, and then with the `FieldInfo` I can read the value from `Original` and set it in `Output`.

My problem lies with the `virtual` property called `Ignored`, the backing field doesn't have a value, but if I read directly from the propertyinfo then I can get the value.

What am I missing with my understanding of how this following line is made up?

```cs
public override string Ignored => "This will get ignored";
```

Is it because it is an override? Or because it uses the `=>` way of setting the property.

If this doesn't have an underlying field, what is the best way to match already used properties so that I only find those that don't have a backing field?

This is just test code at the moment, but for reference, this is basically my method:

```cs
private object CreateObject(object original, Type commonType, Type outputType)
{
    BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public;

    var response = Activator.CreateInstance(outputType, nonPublic: true);
    if (commonType.IsInterface)
    {
        foreach (var info in commonType.GetProperties(flags))
        {
            object clonedValue = info.GetValue(original); //this is simplified for ease
            var method = outputType.GetProperty(info.Name)?.GetSetMethod(nonPublic: true);
            if (method != null)
                method.Invoke(response, flags, null, new object[] { clonedValue }, null);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // ** This only gets the fields of the common type **
        //foreach (var info in commonType.GetFields(flags))
        //{
        //    object clonedValue = this.Clone(info.GetValue(original), implementations);
        //    info.SetValue(response, clonedValue);
        //}

        // ** Testing to get all fields of original type, and then its base type - based on the above commented out code
        var fields = this.GetFieldsRecursive(original.GetType(), flags);
        //var value = commonType.GetProperty("Ignored").GetValue(original); // Proves I can get the value from the original object
        foreach (var info in fields)
        {
            object clonedValue = info.GetValue(original); // this is simplified for ease
            info.SetValue(response, clonedValue);
        }
    }


    return response;
}
```

I hope that makes sense

Any ability to help fill some gaps in my knowledge would be massively appreciated.

Comment: *"get all fields (properties if based on an interface)"* - no, get all properties, regardless of interface or not. How it's backed should be of no concern. Only deal with the public surface area. Also, `?? null` is a no-op (if null, yield null); you can remove that.

Comment: Let me take a stab.  `Value` and `Ignored` are both properties of `Common`, though Ignored is both read-only and virtual.  In `Original`, you implement the `Ignored` property using a lambda that simply returns a literal string.  It likely has no backing field - it doesn't need one - but the property has a value.  I'm pretty sure that if you had implemented it as `{ get { return "ABC"; } }`, you would have had the same behavior.

Comment: @madreflection - In the scenario that I'm dealing with, I know that there will be some private fields that also need copying. Yes, you are right on the `?? null`

Comment: @Flydog57 - Yes, you are correct, if I implement it as you say `{ get { return "asdf"; } }` then I get the same result

Comment: Am currently thinking then that I should base of @madreflection, process all properties first, and then get only non-autogenerated fields, checking to see if their value is different and not been set by one of the properties.

Comment: Remember, properties are code, not data.  Only auto-properties get a magic hidden field, and only when they need one (for example, what purpose would a backing field add to a read-only property). Non-auto-properties get whatever the developer wanted to do.  I'm not quite following what you are trying to do here?